# How to dynamically filter out rows in a Spark dataframe with an exact match?

Tags: python, apache-spark, filter, pyspark

I have a dictionary like so

```
dict = {
"ColA": "A",
"ColB": "B"
}
```

I want to use this dictionary to delete a row in a dataframe, `df`, only if the row matches each value in the dictionary exactly.

So using the input dataframe

```
+------+------+
| ColA | ColB |
+------+------+
| A    | A    |
| A    | B    |
| B    | B    |
+------+------+
```

The output would be

```
+------+------+
| ColA | ColB |
+------+------+
| A    | A    |
| B    | B    |
+------+------+
```

I have tried something like this

```py
 for col in dict:
    df = df.filter(df_to_upsert[col] != row[col])
```

However this would just filter out rows with any matching value in `row_dict`, so in this case every row in the dataframe would be filtered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A typical case using a reduce function:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from functools import reduce

cond = reduce(lambda x,y: x|y, [ col(k)!=v for k,v in dict.items() ])

df.filter(cond).show()
+----+----+
|ColA|ColB|
+----+----+
|   A|   A|
|   B|   B|
+----+----+
```

Comment: Thanks @jxc, that worked perfectly, although it looks a bit cryptic. Would you mind explaining what's happening here?

Comment: @Josh the list comprehension iterates over the array and checks if the column `k` is different than the value. Then `reduce` does a column-wise `OR` operation. If any of the values in the list is `True`, the output will be `True`.